# Decelerate moving platform at targets

Tags: unity, lerp, moving-platforms

I'm trying to make a moving platform move at a constant speed and then when it is near the target start to slow down, I have trying to do this with Lerp, but I'm not satisfied with the results because of two reasons: it goes way too fast between targets, and way too slow near targets.

Also, when it reaches a target it immediately boosts off in the opposite direction. What I want to achieve is for the platform to move steadily between targets, decelerate near targets, and when reaching a target start to accelerate back to the steady speed.

What is the best way for achieving this? Lerp, Smoothstep, other? Thanks! (I'm using Unity)

My current solution:

```
 _dVeloctiy = _velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
 Vector3 newPosition = Vector3.Lerp(_rigidBody.position, currentTargetPosition, _dVeloctiy.magnitude);        
  _rigidBody.MovePosition(newPosition);

  Vector3 dPosition = _rigidBody.position - currentTargetPosition;

  if (dPosition.magnitude > 0.05f)
  {
      _isTurning = false;
  }

  if (dPosition.magnitude < 0.05f && !_isTurning)
  {
      currentTargetPosition = (currentTargetPosition == targetPosition1 ? targetPosition2 : targetPosition1);
      _isTurning = true;
  }
```

Comment: So you have target A and platform B. Then there is the slowdown zone Z which is a distance from A. If distance A->B bigger than Z move a constant speed, and if it is smaller you want it to slowdown relative to the distance to A. So; the speed of the platform has a relation to Z, not the entire journey. Make your speed LERP while inside Z (unrelated to the direction) and while outside Z, use the constant speed?

Comment: Make zone Z a trigger and on the entrance it makes the movement speed smaller.

Comment: You might give bias and gain a look. Lots of info on Google, but here's a link to start:  http://blog.demofox.org/2012/09/24/bias-and-gain-are-your-friend/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best friend is probably to use `Mathf.Sin`, the platform will move at constant speed and decelerate when reaching either side.

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MovingPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        var f = Mathf.Sin(Time.time);
        var position = transform.position;
        position.x = f;
        transform.position = position;
    }
}
```

**Configuration:**

I assume that it is initially placed at the center location between zones it has to reach (platform is the white cube) :

[image]

It will start by moving from the center, if you'd like it to start moving from an edge instead then use `Mathf.Cos`.

Last thing, specifying a longer distance should be pretty easy and I'll let you figure that out :D

Here's a web-app to let you play with sines and so on: https://www.desmos.com/calculator

(remember, use `x * pi` to normalize the sine)

Comment: So simple, yet so good! TY! :)

Comment: Simplicity at its best, I was unsure at first but finally it works really well :D